# How can I determine the dimensions of a spiral trace on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, noise, trace, signal-to-noise

I was designing a circuit that contains some analog signals along with signals of relatively low frequency (2.5 kHz) and I was reading a bit about norms, standards, and good practices for the design of PCBs.  I read that they usually recommend using spiral traces to avoid noisy signals in the traces of the PCB. I looked for information about these famous "spiral traces" but I couldn't find precise information.

These seem to be spiral traces but I'm not sure:

[image]

[image]

- Could you help me better understand how these traces work on PCBs and how I can calculate the space between them?
- Can they be done individually or are they always used in pairs?
- What type of signal are they used for?
- Do they protect the external circuit from the noise generated by the signals they carry or shield the internal signal they carry from external noise?

Comment: That's not what I'd call a spiral. That's a meander.

Comment: The traces you show are differential pairs, the sqwiggly bits are for length matching. I don't think I've heard of "spiral traces", except maybe for some forms of PCB antenna.

Comment: EE top tip: KHz = kelvinhertz. kHz = kilohertz. _"how do I calculate the space between them?"_ From the impedance of the differential pair, your board stackup and dielectric constant of your PCB material. But at 2.5 kHz and analog signal, I would bet that matched impedance is not a concern for you.

Comment: For context, a signal in a PCB track travels at about 200mm per nanosecond, so a 2mm difference will mean that one side of a differential pair will arrive 10ps before the other.  This is important in multi-GHz circuits but at audio frequency it doesn’t matter at all.  If you’re using single-sided signals then it’s generally best to keep the tracks no longer than needed

Comment: Spiral traces are commonly used to create low value inductors.  This is done all the time on microwave ICs (MMICs).  They can also be used on PWB to create transformers.

Answer (score 3):

The traces you show are **meandered**<sup>1</sup>, to equalise their electrical length and thus delay, reducing skew between parallel signals.

The space between the pairs is to give them the correct impedance. It's easy to find suitable calculators online for this geometry.

These traces are differential pairs, but there is no reason single traces should not be meandered to increase their length. It's rarely seen however, as you only need to take this trouble over trace length when signals are very high speed (more than a few 100s of MHz, up to many GHz), and high speed signals tend to be sent differentially rather than single-ended.

You might see a spiral trace forming an inductor, perhaps in circuits of the order of 1 GHz, where discrete components get really tiny, but transmission line circuits are still quite large. I can't find a good public domain illustration at the moment, but just put 'printed spiral inductor' into your favourite image search facility. That search will also find calculators to give their dimensions, when you do need a spiral inductor.

Given the frequency range where they start to become useful, they will be irrelevant to you at 2.5 kHz.

<sup>1</sup>SteveSh also suggests the term serpentine in comments, but I don't think the adjective verbs as well as the noun meander.

Comment: Serpentine is another widely used term for those kinds of traces.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot that can be gleaned from those couple of pictures.

First, what's being shown are differential traces, probably LVDS, but could be something else.

[image]

The spacing between the individual (+/-) traces that make up the pair partially determines the characteristic diff impedance of the pair.  Note the primary determinant of the impedance of a trace is the width of the trace and the distance (height) to its reference plane(s).

That little zig-zag in one of the traces that makes up the pair is to equalize the trace lengths.

[image]

This is done to keep the delays on the + & - traces of the pair the same, which helps to reduce radiated emission.

The meander, or serpentine traces are to equalize the prop delays between those signals, by making their trace lengths the same between the source (driver) and the destination (receiver).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question title, "How can I determine the dimensions of a spiral trace on a PCB?" seems to have gone somewhat unanswered.

While other answers mention the terminology, **meandered** or **serpentine** traces (not **spirals** [image: spiral]), the purpose of doing such meandering is for **length-matching**, **length-tuning**, or **signal delay-matching**. You may find better search results by using these terms.

This is commonly done for **differential pairs**, which is another term you will find useful in your searches.

There are two ways to interpret your question title:

1. How do I decide what amount of length-matching to design into my traces?
2. How do I measure existing trace lengths in this PCB design?

(I initially interpreted your title as the second of these examples; see below.)

In the case of (1), this requires consideration of a variety of factors. As a simple example, consider two differential pairs that carry a signal from one component to another. If the data is correlated, meaning that data on one pair needs to arrive at the same time as the other, then the traces need to be adjusted so that they are of equivalent length. Meandering the traces elongates them, so the shorter pair would be meandered to match the length of the longer one.

In the case of (2), Altium Designer (based on your screenshots) offers several ways to get the dimensions and lengths of the traces. The first is to simply select a *differential net class* in the **PCB Panel** (from the menu: View > Panels > PCB).

[image: Differential Net Classes List in Altium PCB Panel]

Selecting a net class from this list will display the average length, the length of each member net and, based on design rules, highlight if there are any pairs that violate allowable length difference.

There is a great deal of information about how to create meandered traces and use the various tools in the documentation article [Interactively Tuning the Lengths of Your Routes on a PCB in Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/length-tuning-pcb).